# How to connect a 3rd party API to React through Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a React app that's trying to send a *get* request to my Express app. The Express app is then sending a *get* request to a third party API to lookup a stock price. In the network tab of the React app, I see that I have an empty response from localhost:3001. The Express app is console logging the correct data. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

`Price.js`

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Price() {
    const initialPrice = { data: "Loading" };
    const [Price, setPrice] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:3001")
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setPrice(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, []);

    const fetchPrice = () => {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:3001")
            .then((res) => setPrice(res))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
    return (
        <div className="mt-4">
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>Stock Prices</Card.Header>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Text>{Price}</Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={fetchPrice}>
                        Get another price
                    </Button>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`app.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { default: Axios } = require("axios");
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  await Axios.get(
    "https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol=AAPL&token=*hidden*"
  )
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(r.data.c);
      res.send(r.data.c);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

It looks like I needed to send a JSON object back to React, so made this change in `app.js`:

```
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(r.data.c);
      res.send({ c: r.data.c });
    })
```

to structure the data.

Then, in `Price.js`, I changed the code to:

```
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data.c);
                setPrice(res.data.c);
            })
```

to extract the data, once received by the front-end.